# OpenVPN Access to LAN behind client (and vice versa)

Tags: openvpn

I have the following setup:

```
 --------------------------------      ---------------------------------
|Windows server 2012            |      |PFsense router                 |
|Running OpenVPN server         | <--> |Acts as OpenVPN client         |
|Server has WAN only (80.1.1.1)        |LAN: 192.168.1.1 WAN: 90.1.1.1 |
|OpenVPN IP: 10.8.0.1                  |OpenVPN IP: 10.8.0.6
 --------------------------------      ---------------------------------
                                                    ^
                                                    |
                                                    V

                                        -------------------------------
                                        | Windows client              | 
                                        | LAN: 192.168.1.2            |
                                        -------------------------------
```

I want the Windows Server 2012 to be able to access the LAN of the PFsense.
The Windows client in the PFsense LAN needs to be able communicate with the Server 2012 box as well.

How can I do this?

It would be great if I could integrate the OpenVPN network in the LAN network using the same IP range, but I dont think this is possible. For example if one pings 192.168.1.200 it redirects to the VPN IP 10.8.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is all about routing.

You basically will need two things.

- A route on the Windows box directing all the `192.168.1.0/24` to the VPN host.
- An internal route in OpenVPN directing `192.168.1.0/24` to a particular remote client.

So in your OpenVPN server config you could do something like this.

```
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.1
```

In your ccd file for the remote site add

```
iroute 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

For more info, see:

- https://secure-computing.net/wiki/index.php/OpenVPN/Routing
- https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans

Comment: I added route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.1 to the command and restarted OpenVPN. It doenst appear to work. 

When I ping 192.168.1.1 I get this message:
Reply from 109.236.95.209: TTL expired in transit.

It looks like I get those messages for all private IP ranges I try to ping btw.

Here is the output of my routes on the Windows Server machine:http://pastebin.com/fGEKdSVg

Any thoughts?

Comment: I cant add a CCD option when using OpennVPN a a client :(
openvpn[71475]: Options error: --client-config-dir/--ccd-exclusive requires --mode server

Comment: It worked in the end! Route needed to be: route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

You can also push a route to the client (Windows 192.168.1.2) from server (Windows 10.8.0.1) with **push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.0.0"** 
in the openvpn-server.conf file

Answer (score 0):

in the ccd file of that client, add "iroute 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0"
also in the configuration of the server add line: route 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0